# How to find a particular object in a array

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

How to find a particular object in a array.

Below is my code

```
r.table("tablename").filter(
  function(doc){
      return r.expr(["value1","value2"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to add .contains in return statement. Try the rectified one -

```
r.table("tablename").filter(
  function(doc){
    return r.expr(["value1","value2"]).contains(doc("someKey"));
 });
```